# how to show expandable list when we click on particular header in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show expandable list only when I click header section "2". For this I have edited this code from some where

Here my main requirement is i want to load my own array list data when i click header section "2" like(arrayForBool = "hai","how","fine" data when i clicked that header section 2)

```
  #import "ShowList.h"
#import "MFSideMenu.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ShowList (){

    NSString *imgUrlStr;
    UIImageView *imgNew ;
    UILabel *usrNameLbl;
    NSString *usrName;

    UIViewController *demoViewController;
    UIColor *bg_color;
    NSMutableArray *imageArr;

    BOOL isfirstTimeRun;
    UIImageView * userimage;

    NSMutableArray  *arrayForBool;
    NSArray *sectionTitleArray;
    NSArray * sublist;
}

@end

@implementation ShowList

@synthesize myTab;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        //Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrayForBool = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    sectionTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.myTab.backgroundColor = bg_color;
    self.myTab.delegate = self;
    self.myTab.dataSource = self;
    self.myTab.scrollEnabled = YES;

    myTab.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self initialization];
}

-(void)initialization
{
    sectionTitleArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:

                       @"Raju",
                       @"Strawberry",
                       @"Grapes",
                       @"Orange",
                       @"Banana",
                       @"Papaya",
                       @"Guava",
                       @"pineapple",
                       nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[sectionTitleArray count]; i++) {

        [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView DataSource and Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {

        return section+2;
    }

    else
        return 0;

    return arrayForBool.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellid=@"hello";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
    }

    BOOL manyCells  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

    /********** If the section supposed to be closed *******************/
    if(!manyCells)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.text=@"";
    }

    /********** If the section supposed to be Opened *******************/

    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"      %@ %d",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section],indexPath.row+1];

        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    /********** Add a custom Separator with cell *******************/
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, myTab.frame.size.width, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [sectionTitleArray count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    [myTab reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue]) {

        return 40;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}

#pragma mark - Creating View for TableView Section

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280,40)];
    sectionView.tag=section;
    UILabel *viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, myTab.frame.size.width-10, 40)];
    viewLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    viewLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    viewLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    viewLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]];
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];

    /********** Add a custom Separator with Section view *******************/
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, myTab.frame.size.width, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [sectionView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    /********** Add UITapGestureRecognizer to SectionView   **************/
    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [sectionView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return  sectionView;
}

#pragma mark - Table header gesture tapped

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

    BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

    if (indexPath.section==1) {

        [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
    }

    [myTab reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

@end
```

Here my requirement is simple i want load "hai","how","fine" data instead of Straberry1 ,Straberry2,Straberry3 when i click header section "2" please help me some one i am completly new for ios

[image]

Comment: post what  exception you are getting

Comment: array indexed bounds exception please modify my code and post that then your decrease my pain

Comment: @m.v.n.kalyani - Is it crashing right away or when you click on header2? Include the full error in your question.

Comment: i have actually edited 5this code from some where i am not understand how to modified this based on my requirement and i want load my arrayForboll dat in expandable list when we clicked thar header "2"

Comment: i have edited this code please help me

Comment: there are many open source codes available for this...try one of them

Comment: i have edited above code since long time please modified that code accroding to my requirement

Comment: Your issue resolved?